# how to make Text Vertical in Excel by using the EPPLUS?

Tags: c#, excel

how to make Text Vertical in Excel by using the EPPLUS?

I couldn't find the api. For an example, "TEXT" in a cell should looks like

```
T
E
X
T
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can achive that with the "TextRotation" property, you basically give an integer value equivalent to the amounth of degrees you want to turn the text, for your example it will be 180 so you can do it like this:

```
myExcelSheet.Cells[row, column].Style.TextRotation = 180;
```

Hope this helps, greetings.